# How to set URL encoded hyperlinks in libre office?

Tags: openoffice.org, libreoffice

Want to set a hyperlink containing deliberately an URL encoded (aka percent encoded) hash '#' in libre office Version 4.0.3.3 . This should be done by inserting an '%23', but whenever I save this URL it seems to be rewritten to a '#' - which breaks this URI.
So, how to set an percent encoded character in libre office?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming. Its about how to use an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround: in the `hyperlink` dialog, do not choose `internet` but `document` and paste your url encoded URI into the `path` field, click ok - and voila.